# apt-get ... "Config is in use."?

Tags: apt

At the end of a pretty ordinary `sudo apt-get install ...`, I'm seeing a "**Config is in use.**" line.

**Is this a problem?**  If so how might I fix it?

*Have searched for apt "Config is in use." but can't seem to find any leads on this one.  I've seen this before, but am just getting around to chasing it down.*

Thanks!  :-)

---

GNU/Linux - Debian Buster 10.2

```
$ uname 
Linux <hostname> 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

apt-get --version
apt 1.8.2 (amd64)
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 Pkg:  Debian APT planner interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: Debian deb file
 Idx: Debian dsc file
 Idx: Debian control file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file
 Idx: EIPP scenario file
```

---

### Example 1

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libxml2-dev libjson-c-dev libbz2-dev libpcre3-dev ncurses-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
libbz2-dev is already the newest version (1.0.6-9.2~deb10u1).
libbz2-dev set to manually installed.
libpng-dev is already the newest version (1.6.36-6).
libxml2-dev is already the newest version (2.9.4+dfsg1-7+b3).
libxml2-dev set to manually installed.
libncurses-dev is already the newest version (6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2).
libncurses-dev set to manually installed.
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1d-0+deb10u2).
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1d-0+deb10u2).
libpcre3-dev is already the newest version (2:8.39-12).
libpcre3-dev set to manually installed.
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-1).
zlib1g-dev set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libmhash2 librasqal3 librdf0 libxslt1-dev libyajl-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-doc librtmp-dev
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcmis-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libraptor2-dev librasqal3-dev librdf0-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libjson-c-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 5 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 458 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.64.0-4 [419 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjson-c-dev amd64 0.12.1+ds-2 [38.8 kB]
Fetched 458 kB in 1s (384 kB/s)          
(Reading database ... 552014 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcmis-dev (0.5.2-1) ...
Removing librdf0-dev (1.0.17-1.1+b1) ...
Removing librasqal3-dev (0.9.32-1+b1) ...
Removing libraptor2-dev (2.0.14-1+b1) ...
Removing libcurl4-gnutls-dev:amd64 (7.64.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 551802 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.64.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64 (7.64.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjson-c-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libjson-c-dev_0.12.1+ds-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjson-c-dev:amd64 (0.12.1+ds-2) ...
Setting up libjson-c-dev:amd64 (0.12.1+ds-2) ...
Setting up libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64 (7.64.0-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Config is in use.
```

### Example 2:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libmhash2 librasqal3 librdf0 libxslt1-dev libyajl-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,343 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 551845 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcmis-0.5-5v5 (0.5.2-1) ...
Removing librdf0:amd64 (1.0.17-1.1+b1) ...
Removing librasqal3:amd64 (0.9.32-1+b1) ...
Removing libmhash2:amd64 (0.9.9.9-7+b1) ...
Removing libxslt1-dev:amd64 (1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1) ...
Removing libyajl-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Config is in use.
```

### Example 3 - not seeing it here

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.6).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libmhash2 librasqal3 librdf0 libxslt1-dev libyajl-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you connected your package manager to snapper?

Comment: @JdeBP, I do use btrfs and snapper.  Not sure how it might be 'connected' to dpkg, apt or the like.  This seems to work fine `$sudo snapper -c root list`.

Comment: @JdeBP, Oh, you've given me an idea.  Yes, as I recall there are snapshots made around package installs.  I'll look into that further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JdeBP hinted that this had something to do with **`snapper`** (an automatic snapshot utility for btrfs filesystems).

I ended up deleting all of my old root snapshots, i.e.

```
# snapper -c root delete <first>-<lasts> #e.g. snapper -c root delete 7-945
```

and this seems to have fixed this issue, at least for now.

---

Note that in `/etc/defaults/snapper` you'll see the lines

```
# if you want to disable snapshot per install/upgrade, then set "yes"
DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT="no"
```

which turns on or off automatic apt snapshots (that may occur before and after an apt operation).

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80snapper holds this code:

```
  DPkg::Pre-Invoke  { "if [ -e /etc/default/snapper ]; then . /etc/default/snapper; fi; if [ -x /usr/bin/snapper ] && [ ! x$DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT = 'xyes' ] && [ -e /etc/snapper/configs/root ]; then rm -f /var/tmp/snapper-apt || true ; snapper create -d apt -c number -t pre -p > /var/tmp/snapper-apt || true ; snapper cleanup number || true ; fi"; };
  DPkg::Post-Invoke { "if [ -e /etc/default/snapper ]; then . /etc/default/snapper; fi; if [ -x /usr/bin/snapper ] && [ ! x$DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT = 'xyes' ] && [ -e /var/tmp/snapper-apt ]; then snapper create -d apt -c number -t post --pre-number=`cat /var/tmp/snapper-apt` || true ; snapper cleanup number || true ; fi"; };
```

.. or reformat

```
#if vi :set ts=8
#  DPkg::Pre-Invoke  { 
#       "
#       if [ -e /etc/default/snapper    ]; then . /etc/default/snapper; fi;     # Set environment variable:  DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT ="no"
#
#       if [ -x /usr/bin/snapper        ] && [ ! x$DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT = 'xyes' ] && [ -e /etc/snapper/configs/root ]; then 
#               rm -f                                            /var/tmp/snapper-apt           || true ; 
#               snapper create  -d apt  -c number  -t pre  -p  > /var/tmp/snapper-apt           || true ;       # -d dscp;  -c cleanup-algo;  -t type;  -p print#
#               snapper cleanup            number                                               || true ;       # trim old or excessive snapshots
#       fi"; 
#  };
#
#
#  DPkg::Post-Invoke { 
#       "
#       if [ -e /etc/default/snapper    ]; then . /etc/default/snapper; fi; 
#       if [ -x /usr/bin/snapper        ] && [ ! x$DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT = 'xyes' ] && [ -e /var/tmp/snapper-apt ]; then 
#               snapper create  -d apt  -c number  -t post               --pre-number=`cat /var/tmp/snapper-apt` || true ; 
#               snapper cleanup number                                                                           || true ; 
#       fi"; 
#  };
```